# iOS video not playing in mobile safari

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming, wifi, 3g-network

I have this really annoying problem that I cannot seem to solve.

We have some short clips on our server that we are trying to view via mobile safari. The weird thing is that we are able to view the movie on mobile safari when our iPhones are on 3g, and not when we are on WiFi.

It gets weirder that we are able to view the movie sometimes on wifi and not other times.

Here is the link in question:
http://bit.ly/Za0xBA

Why would the link play via 3g and not via wifi? Are there some settings in there that would be stopping? We even tried to wireshark the connection via the iOS simulator and what was going on and it looks like the video is downloading fine.

This is driving us nuts!

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming issue.  Its more of a network issue. But you should add the section of code that is playing the video for others to see.

Comment: even taking the programming issue out of it, i tried to navigate to the url above with my iphone through safari straight while on wifi and it wont play. but on 3g it does.

Comment: Then it sounds like you have a network router issue on your wi-fi.  This is for programming questions.